# Change button href based on current page url

Tags: javascript

I have a button in my website menu that leads to a store locator but I need the button to link to one of 3 different pages depending on the page the visitor is currently on.

The button currently just links to /find-a-store but I need it to know the first part of the page path and include that in the button href

for example if the visitor is on a page that contains mywebsite.com/cars the button href should change to mywebsite.com/cars/find-a-store

if they're on a page that contains /bikes then mywebsite.com/bikes/find-a-store

and finally if the page contains /trucks then mywebsite.com/trucks/find-a-store

The button has an id if that helps me to target and change the button based on its ID.

Comment: What have you tried, please post the HTML and code that you have tried to resolve this/  In addition show what you have now and what your actual result would look like.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct url:

```js
let type = document.location.pathname.split('/').filter(x => x.length > 0)[0];
let url = `/${type}/find-a-store`;
```

Now you need to set the href of your link. Since we don't have the HTML I can't tell you exactly what that will be but generally:

```js
// this selects the link with id="coolID"
let link = document.querySelector('#coolID');

link.href = url;
```